# how to use netstat -nb in python

Tags: python, windows, netstat

I want to use `netstat -nb` in python but every code that i write i get the same msg: *"The requested operation requires elevation."*
The last code that i try is

```
import os    
output_command = os.popen("netstat -nb").readlines()
```

and i try also

```
import subprocess    
program_list = subprocess.run(["netstat", "-nb"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode("utf-8")
program_list = program_list.split("\r\n")
```

Comment: Run your *cmd* as *Administrator* and check.

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: Refer https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-run-command-prompt-as-an-administrator

Comment: if this is windows related pls. tag it as windows. My netstat under ubuntu has no -b option

Comment: I run my cmd as Administrator but I get the same msg again

Answer (score 0):

import os
a=os.popen('netstat -nb').read()
print("\n Connections ",a )

try this, it's working!